# making same-parity function with g . w in mit scheme

Tags: lisp, mit-scheme

I am trying to write a function that takes one or more integers and returns a list of all the arguments that have the same even-odd parity as the first argument, for example

```
(same-parity 1 2 3 4 5 6 7)->(1 3 5 7)
(same-parity 2 3 4 5 6)->(2 4 6).
```

my code is

```
(define (same-parity g . w)
    (define (iter-parity items)
        (if (= (length items) 1)
            (if (= (remainder items 2) (remainder g 2))
                item
                '())
            (if (= (remainder g 2) (remainder (car items) 2))
                (cons (car items) (iter-parity (cdr items)))
                (iter-parity (cdr items)))))
    (cons g (iter-parity w)))
```

when try this `(same-parity (list 1 2 3 4))`, I got an error message: 
   the object (), passed as the first argument to car, is not the correct type.

Can I somebody tell me what is going on?

Comment: This is your first question here so I've taken the liberty of identing the code so it's more readable. In future please do this so that we can understand your code :)

Comment: Having `nil` as the base case very often leads to a more natural recursion pattern than a list of length 1.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Your code**

Here's a refactoring proposal, keeping with your basic structure:

```
(define (same-parity g . w)
  (define filter-predicate? (if (odd? g) odd? even?))

  (define (iter-parity items)
    (if (null? items)
        '()
        (if (filter-predicate? (car items))
            (cons (car items) (iter-parity (cdr items)))
            (iter-parity (cdr items)))))

  (cons g (iter-parity w)))
```

Note that it is more idiomatic

- to use the procedures `odd?` and `even?` rather than `remainder`
- to have as a base case when the list is empty, not when it has only one item (in your code this clearly avoids repetition as a positive effect).

Also, since there is a built-in `filter` procedure in Scheme, you could express it as follows:

```
(define (same-parity g . w)
  (cons g (filter (if (odd? g) odd? even?) w)))
```

**Your question**

As for your question regarding `(same-parity (list 1 2 3 4))`: you need either (as described in your specification) use your procedure like so

```
 (same-parity 1 2 3 4)
```

or to use `apply` here:

```
> (apply same-parity (list 1 2 3 4))
'(1 3)
```

because `apply` will transform `(same-parity (list 1 2 3 4))` (1 parameter, a list) into `(same-parity 1 2 3 4)` (4 parameters).